# The difference between onratingbarchanged and onratingbarclicked android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ratingbar

I've got a rating bar in my android application which is in a custom adapter. I've set the ratingbar to listen for a change and on that change, update the database through a cient/server architecture. I then use the custom adapter in a master/details view. The problem is, everytime I load the details page on click of the left-hand list item, it updates the rating bar. This is not what I want. I only want to update the rating bar once it's been clicked, not everytime the adapter is used.

Is there way to only fire an event when it is clicked and not changed. Is there a major difference between onratingbarchanged (which it is currently) and onratingbarclicked (which I'm assuming is what I should be doing?)

My code is as follows:

```
    //Should this rather be setOnClickListener()???
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener()
    {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser)
        {
            questions.get(position).TotalRating = rating;
            String newRating = "" + rating;
            ratingBar.setRating(rating);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "Rating set to:  " + rating + " for the position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String question = questions.get(position).Question;

            //Create XML with both position/question to send to doAsyncTask
            serverUpdateRating update = new serverUpdateRating();
            Document doc;
            try 
            {
                //Create an XML document with question from the selected position as well as the new rating

                doc = x.createDoc();
                Element tutor = doc.createElement("Update");

                tutor.appendChild(x.UpdateRating(doc, newRating, question));

                doc.appendChild(tutor);

                //Create a string
                String s = x.getStringFromDocument(doc);

                String result = update.execute(s).get();
                //return either true (updated correctly) or false (problem)

                if (result.equals("true"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Rating successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Rating update unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know if there is a workaround for this, but if there is, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score -1):

You could use `fromUser` in `onRatingChanged`

[onRatingChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.html#onRatingChanged(android.widget.RatingBar,%20float,%20boolean)) :

> [...] fromUser    True if the rating change was initiated by a user's touch
>   gesture or arrow key/horizontal trackbell movement.